# AS3: can't figure out Math.random

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, math, random

I'm very bad at math, so i can't figure out why this isn't working. It should calculate a random number between 0 and 360.

```
var minDegree:int = 0
var maxDegree:int = 360

function randomDegree (minDegree:Number, maxDegree:Number):Number 
{
    return (Math.random() * (maxDegree - minDegree + minDegree));
    trace(randomDegree)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you actually want integers, right? This is the actual code:

```
private function randRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}
```

I'm posting it because @Xenophage's answer is not correct. And it's not correct because of the fact that Math.random *Returns a pseudo-random number n, where 0 <= n < 1.* ([reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29)). What this means is that if you pass `0` as minimum and `360` as maximum, the biggest number you can get is 359 because:

```
(Math.random() * (maxDegree - minDegree) + minDegree);
(0.99999 * (360 - 0) + 0) = 359
```

So the upper solution would work better :) If you are not looking for an integer - let me know.

Edit: I've made the random to return more precise number, as if it was simply 0.99 it would calculate to 354 instead of 359. Either ways won't go up to 360.
And yes, I know you need degrees, so `0` is similar to `360` if you are not doing some precise calculations, but I had to mention it as it's a `Math.random` problem, not a degrees problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, move the closing parenthesis over a little. Multiplying the difference between max and min, then adding min back on to bring the value back into the proper range. I find it easy to try some examples using a simple calculator and seeing if the results make sense.

```
var minDegree:int = 0
var maxDegree:int = 360

function randomDegree (minDegree:Number, maxDegree:Number):Number 
{
    return Math.min(maxDegree, Math.random() * (maxDegree - minDegree) + minDegree + .01);
}

trace(randomDegree(minDegree, maxDegree));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! One more question though, this doesn't give a trace output, have an idea why?

Comment: Your tracing the function (so you'll just get back Function) plus your tracing it after the return statement

Comment: Well because it first returns the value :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov - that's how it was in the original question, doesn't make the answer wrong or bad (eg. not deserving of a downvote).

Comment: I did it because the answer is not 100% correct. Will write my own now :)

Comment: AS3 is not my specialty, but I know a math brain fart when I see one!

Comment: @Xenophage check out my answer - you will understand why :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov You forgot to initialize and set your variables in your answer below ;)